# java GUI setText and append doesn't work from another class

Tags: java, swing, client-server, jtextarea, settext

I have just started looking at client and servers and I am linking a client to a gui, so far I have made it so when you enter text in the `JTextField` (called "Input") it sends it to `Client.java` and is printed out to make sure it works.
How ever when I set something to be sent back and appended onto a `JTextArea` (called "Output") it is sent across and can be printed out but it is not set to the `JTextArea`.
I have also tried using `setText` and that doesn't work either.

When I run `Client.java` it starts and in the cmd it says

```
sent
```

then in the cmd for the `ClientGUI.java` it says

```
it worked.
```

which is what was meant to be sent to the gui not the cmd.

How can I make it append text to the `JTextArea` from class `Client`?

FULL Code:

`ClientGUI.java:`

```
private void InputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String input = Input.getText();
    Client c = new Client();
    c.input(input);
}                                     

public void output() {
    Output.append("it worked.");
    //Output.append(null);
}
```

`Client.java:`

```
public void input(String input) {
    System.out.println(input);
}

public void startUP() {
    System.out.println("sent");
    ClientGUI cg = new ClientGUI();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {          
    Client c = new Client();
    c.startUP();
    new ClientGUI().setVisible(true);

    try {
        Socket skt = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
        System.out.print("Received string: '");

        while (!in.ready()) {}
        String output = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(output); // Read one line and output it

        System.out.print("'\n");
        in.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be much better to understand your problem if you put your complete code here..

Comment: I have changed it to add the full code, wasn't that much more anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `main` method instead of :

```
new ClientGUI().setVisible(true);
```

use:

```
ClientGUI cgui = new ClientGUI();
cgui.setVisible(true);
```

Change :

```
c.startUP();
```

To

```
c.startUP(cgui);
```

And change `startUP` method of `Client.java` as follows:

```
    public void startUP(final ClientGUI cg){
       new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                 System.out.println("sent");
                 cg.output();
            }
        }, 
        5000 
);
```

Comment: for ClientGUI cgui = new ClientGUI().setVisible(true); I getincompatible types , required: CLientGUI, found: void